# Html email to outook 2003/2007

Tags: c++, html, css, outlook, html-email

I usualy just find answers on StackOverflow but couldn't find anything good about this subject.
I have a C++ program that needs to send formatted html with CSS (and embeded images) and the main e-mail client we are intersted in is Outlook 2003/2007. I have a HTML page ready and I can send it from IE (file -> send page by mail) and it is ok, once I have my program read the same file and send it none of the CSS actually works, only the simple HTML.

Thanks

Comment: How is the CSS implemented? Keep in mind external stylesheets is not always supported (but should be in Outlook 2003/2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, external CSS is not supported in most email clients.

Also, if you are using background css, you will find several email clients (GMail for example) wont support them. Though [there are work arounds](http://blog.mailchimp.com/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/)

I tend to make all CSS inline and keep it as simple as possible.

What are you trying to do with you CSS?

Edit:

This is how i got it working. Using a combination of inline CSS and HTML.

```
<td background="Path/to/image.jpg" style="background-image:url(path/to/image.jpg);"></td>
```

Edit2:
For Outlook 2007, try adding the repeat. So

```
Background-repeat: No-repeat;
```

Edit3 :

If all that fails. [Try this](http://newbitsontheblog.com/outlook-2007-css-background-image/)

Comment: As I wrote above I am trying to have it work for outlook, I am trying (as you guessed) to have it display background images although I am starting to think this is almost impossible
Does the CSS have to be inlined?

(sorry for the former comments, I hit Enter before they were done)

Comment: Your best bet is to checkout the link i linked to in my above post. Yes showing back ground images using CSS is tricky but not impossible. I did it only last week using the details in the page i linked to. If you try that and still have no luck, let me know and i will have another look at my code and paste it here.

Comment: The image should be embedded (vs linked to external source) I know this is not ideal, this is what we're trying to do.

Comment: Added a code example :)
You will need to put the full URL though because the email needs something to link to. Unless you actually attach the image, but ive not done that before. Your better off putting in the whole url even if it is on your site.

Comment: That is why I specifically wrote "css" because I didn't want to use the background html attribute (whcih actually works).

Comment: Fine, but to use the CSS you need to put the absolute URL. I used the HTMl as a backup. But for Outlook only you should be fine with CSS as long as its using an absolute URL E.g. http://www.site.com/path/to/image.jpg

Comment: BTW both these approaches still don't work for outlook 2007 (but do work for outlook express and thunderbird)

Comment: Ah! In which case add background-repeat: repeat-y; or no repeat etc

Comment: Actually what we're trying to do is something like this code snippet:
"<div id="whatever" style="background: url('data:image/png;base64,ivborw0kggoaaaansuheugaa....'">data </div>
but I would be content with the absolute url working right now.

Comment: I have already all the repeat stuff, still not showing images (background and forground) for outlook 2007 when the images are displayed this way "image/png,base64 .... "

Comment: Hmmmm im all out of ideas though. Will post a link to another potentially useful page. See my initial answer

Comment: Lex, your CSS is incorrect, it should  be: `<td background="Path/to/image.jpg" style="background-image:url(path/to/image.jpg);"></td>`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I actually cought that one already (although browsers handle background just fine)

Comment: Might this be an issue emaneting from the IE that is installed on the specific test computer?